# How to specify argument type in a dynamically typed language, i.e. Python?

Tags: java, python, dynamic, static

Is there any such equivalent of Java

```
String myMethod (MyClass argument) {...}
```

in Python?

Thank you, Tomas

Comment: The language wouldn't be dynamically-typed if there was.

Comment: One of the best things about going to Java was not having to guess at types, sometimes when things were poorly documented you could fit them together like puzzle pieces, just knowing you NEED to construct class A and and feed it to class B to get things to work is really nice.  This is one of my least favorite things about dynamic languages--I firmly believe that putting help into the code helps save everyone down the line time, even if it makes you type an extra 10 characters.

Comment: @delnan Common Lisp has dynamic typing and allows declaring types. It is optional, but the compiler can generate very efficient code if you specify types.

Comment: @gpeche: I doubt that this is equivalent to Java type annotations - they are enforced at compiletime; but in a dynamically-typed language (or even in a statically-typed language with a variant type), the type of the value a variable(/variant) refers to at a given time is undecidable via static analysis -> can only be checked at runtime.

Comment: @delnan Not equivalent, but quite good as it can generate a lot of warnings at compile time. Obviously the language semantics do not allow for more, but if you are used to have your code compile without warnings, then it is basically the same.

Comment: @Bill K - I see your point, but I think it's a bit of false security. Sure, it's nice to know that the `org.foo.Bar` constructor takes an `org.foo.Blort` instance... but what does it matter if you get a `RuntimeException` a while later because the value of `Blort.getColor()` changed? There are things that static type checking helps, and then there's the other 99% of operational details :P (But like I said... I do understand why it's good.)

Comment: @detly I don't really consider it security but help.  Many APIs I've dealt with are just not documented, and if your dynamic language needs something with, say, a getColor, getModel and getYear method (car) but doesn't help you know that is what you need, you have to go through a LOT of trial and error to figure it out.  It SHOULD be documented, but in java it is just never a question, you know this takes a Car and you know exactly what a Car needs to implement without questions--also you know this in a deterministic manner without ever leaving the line of code you are typing.

Comment: @Bill K — so you know you need a `Car` ... my point is: so what? A green one? A Ford? A Ford only if it's green? There could be another hundred constraints on that API, all of which will stop your program from working. Without documentation, static type checking means almost nothing. The trial and error required to figure out that it's a car is nothing compared to the trial and error required to satisfy some *really* obscure semantic requirement.

Comment: @detly no, not at all. IF you accept a car, all subclasses of car are acceptable (unless you are dealing with a truly horrific OO programmer). If you truly needed a specifically constrained car (with a red attribute), at least you KNOW to pass in car and you aren't passing in "String" and seeing an error message saying "that's not red". Honestly I'm not trying to convince you, just relaying personal experience--in moving to Java having the types specified made my life noticeably easier. I'm a terrible guesser of other peoples intentions--if I wasn't I'd probably be fine with dynamic languages.

Comment: @detly Sorry to continue, but just wanted to point out that most dynamic programmers will simply attempt to get the red attribute and the error will say "That object has no red attribute".  This tells you nothing about how to find or make an object with the red attribute or even what type the red attribute is supposed to be (Color, RGB, byte[], ...)  How do you proceed from this point?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. (And more stuff to round this up to 15 characters...)

Comment: And can I tell anyhow that such method only works with instances of MyClass, in other words, how can I tell anyone using myMethod that he has to pass an argument which is an instance of MyClass?

Comment: Tomas, in debugging environments, you can use isinstance() and issubclass() methods to alert by raising an exception or a simple print message.

Comment: And `type()`. As noted below, not recommended practice -- unpythonic.

Comment: They don't have to pass an instance of MyClass, unless the code specifically checks for it. They can pass any object that has the methods and attributes the code requires regardless of said object's provenance.

Answer (score 12):

No, there is not.

In fact, checking types is considered "un-Pythonic", because an object of any type that looks enough like the expected type should be treated equally.

Comment: "looks enough like the expected type" --- means "supports enough of the requisite interface and semantics of" (search Google on "Python" and "duck typing" for related discussions).

Comment: Because of Python's late binding it's actually impossible to tell the type of *anything* (beside literals) before executing the code. So even if you could specify types, it would do you not much good.

Answer (score 8):

Python 3.x has function annotations where you can declare argument and return types:

```
def myMethod(argument: MyClass) -> str:
   ...
```

But currently Python does nothing with them, they serve as documentation only.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to say that I'm in full agreement that type checking is evil. But python is also incredibly flexible and I'm in the mood to be evil. This code will take effect at runtime and not compile time. You could do something similar for return type. Something like this could be useful for debugging and, because it's a decorator, it's easy enough to remove.

For it to be useful for debugging you would have to have a situation where two types had all the same attributes that were getting accessed but with different semantics. So that's a pretty limited case. Other than that, you're about to get a typerror anyways when this code runs. The good news is that **this is almost never a problem**. I really don't know why people from statically typed languages make such a big deal over it.

```
def types(*args, **kwargs):
    arg_types = args
    kwarg_types = kwargs
    def decorator(f):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            for arg, arg_type in zip(args, arg_types):
                if not isinstance(arg, arg_type):
                    raise TypeError("Wrong type suckah")
            for kw, arg in kwargs.items():
                if not isinstance(arg, kwarg_types[kw]):
                    raise TypeError("this is a bad error message")
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return func
    return decorator

@types(int, str, bool, flag=bool)
def demo(i, strng, flag=False):
    print i, strng, flag

demo(1, "foo", True)

try:
    demo("foo", "bar", flag="foobar")
except TypeError:
    print "busted on posargs"

try:
    demo(1, "foo", flag=2)
except TypeError:
    print "busted on keyargs"

try:
    demo(1, "foo", 3)
except TypeError:
    print "no use sneaking it through"
```

Comment: I love creative (ab)use of decorators.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> In Python, it's the program's
>   responsibility to use built-in
>   functions like isinstance() and
>   issubclass() to test variable types
>   and correct usage. Python tries to
>   stay out of your way while giving you
>   all you need to implement strong type
>   checking.

from [Why is Python a dynamic language and also a strongly typed language](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language). Also

> In a dynamically typed language, a
>   variable is simply a value bound to a
>   name; the value has a type -- like
>   "integer" or "string" or "list" -- but
>   the variable itself doesn't. You could
>   have a variable which, right now,
>   holds a number, and later assign a
>   string to it if you need it to change.

Further, isinstance() and issubclass() can be used to do type-checking. If you want to make sure that argument is of MyClass type, you can have a check inside the function. You can even type-cast the value of the argument (if you have a constructor accepting such value) and assign it to my_object.